# html 5 videojs will not appear on iphone 3G

Tags: html, html5-video, mp4, ogg, video.js

its all messed up on the iphone. Here is the code

```
<video id="my_video_1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls
preload="auto" width="540" height="425" poster="/sites/all/themes/iws/videos/image001.jpg"
data-setup="{}">
<source src="/sites/all/themes/iws/videos/overview-IWS-proposal.mp4" type="video/mp4">
<source src="/sites/all/themes/iws/videos/overview-IWS-proposal.ogg" type="video/ogg">
<source src="/sites/all/themes/iws/videos/overview-IWS-proposal.webm" type="video/webm">

</video>
```

The poster picture and play button will show, however the play button is all messed up (not centered and wildly stretched out in the bottom right hand corner) and it doesn't even play when you click it. This is when you are connected to wifi

When you are not connected to wifi (3g), it simply shows a play button with a strikethrough through it (like a no smoking sign)

Here is the page for further documentation

http://www.imageworksstudio.com/content/video-testing

Comment: I didn't get what your question is. did you mean you cannot play your html5 video on iphone ? because I tested it with iphone simulator, and working well.

Comment: The big play button is big on my iPhone 4 iOS 5 also. Do you know of any styles that might be conflicting with the button's? Or is the whole player being floated/positioned in a way that might be affecting it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

had a bit of an issue myself, not sure if it's the same thing: older iPhones can only handle older codecs. from apple -

> Safari on the desktop supports any media the installed version of QuickTime can play. This includes media encoded using codecs QuickTime does not natively support, provided the codecs are installed on the user’s computer as QuickTime codec components.
>
> Safari on iOS (including iPad) currently supports uncompressed WAV and AIF audio, MP3 audio, and AAC-LC or HE-AAC audio. HE-AAC is the preferred format.
>
> Safari on iOS (including iPad) currently supports MPEG-4 video (Baseline profile) and QuickTime movies encoded with H.264 video (Baseline profile) and one of the supported audio types.
>
> iPad and iPhone 3G and later support H.264 Baseline profile 3.1. Earlier versions of iPhone support H.264 Baseline profile 3.0.

https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/Device-SpecificConsiderations/Device-SpecificConsiderations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009523-CH5-SW1

Answer (score 0):

This is likely an encoding issue. For 3G, you need to encode with the Baseline@3.0 codec profile while for 3GS, you can encode with Baseline@3.0 or Baseline@3.1 codec.

Here is a helpful link:
http://blog.zencoder.com/2010/09/30/how-to-encode-video-for-mobile-use/